# Combine flags and options using argparse

Tags: python, argparse, flags

Using argparse, I know that I can obtain the behaviour of the `tar` command out of the box, e.g. `tar -xvzf file`; however, I am limited to only having one argument per group of flags which must be placed at the end (`f`).

How could I implement the following syntax in argparse, basically joining flags and arguments together?

`myprint -elf 500 test.txt`, where `e` is a flag pointing that the output should be sent via email, `l` (loop) is an argument which requires a value (`500`) and repeats the command every 500s, and `f` is the file which should be parsed.

The effect of `myprint -elf 500 test.txt` should be the same as the one of `myprint -lfe 500 test.txt` or `myprint -fel test.txt 500`.

Thanks!

Comment: You would probably be better off writing your own argument parser if you want that behavior... I personally would just stick with argparse conventions, as it makes things clearer

Comment: Not possible.  'myprint -e -l 500 -f test.txt' is the normal `argparse input.  `-el 500` or even `-el500' works.  But nothing involving all 3.  Anything else fights both `argparse` conventions, and (I suspect) most  user expectations.